# How to see what applications are listening on what ports in Azure App Service?

Tags: azure, port, azure-web-app-service

An app I ran tried to use certain ports, and threw an error saying they are already being used.  Without having to pick random ports, how can I see which ones are already being used?  Also, how can I see which apps/services are using those ports.

There is no access to netstat.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what you're asking, but the only inbound ports on a web app (app service) from the outside world are 80 and 443. These end up getting mapped to ports assigned to your app (and accessible via environment variables).